# CQ5 Author instance sidekick not visible on the page

Tags: aem

All of sudden Sidekick not showing up today on any page in the cq5 author instance. Please help me if anyone have seen the same kind of issue before and what could be the reason. I'm not sure if any of my team member changed any configuration changes in the author instance.

Comment: Check the developer console and see if there is any JavaScript error being thrown.

Comment: I'm not able to access clinetcontext store.init.js, please let me know why I'm not able to access?

Comment: Please post the details of the error and other findings. It is impossible to say why without knowing anything.

Comment: I have noticed  using front developer tools that on every page load this element(http://localhost:4502/etc/clientcontext/new/content/jcr:content/stores.init.js?path=%2Fcontent%2Fmyproject%2Fen-US%2Fhome&cq_ck=1456384798500) keeps loading and spinning icon keeps rotating and also browser throwing  kill or wait alert for every few sec.

Comment: The above specified element loading fine in my other environments.

Answer (score 0):

Take thread dumps and see if a thread is stuck. I have had a similar issue where one of the component code was stuck and thread dump helped me figure out where it was breaking.